# Does each zone in a two-zone heating system have its own pilot light?

Tags: hvac

I have two zone heating, in the basement and upstairs where we really live. The pilot light is lit downstairs, but the heat isn't working upstairs (the air is not getting hot). Is there also a pilot light in our unit upstairs that may have blown out that is keeping the upstairs cold?

Comment: do you have two furnaces, or one furnace and electronic dampers controlling heat to the two zones?